How to remove a widget from screen and refresh the recycleview?
This is my first question, I'm new on kivy...
I want to add or remove a card from a list of card in a recyclingview.
So I have a screen with a text box and a button that I use to add the card to the RV, and on each card on the list, I have a trash button to remove the card from the list.
Now I can add the card to the list, but I don't know how to remove the card from the list.
here the code:
.Py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import Class
import pickle


try:
    with open("list1.pickle","rb") as f:
        list1 = pickle.load(f)
except:
    list1 = []

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):

    def add_card(self):
        text = self.ids.text_field.text
        obj = Class.Reparto(text)
        self.ids.text_field.text = ""
        list1.append(obj)
        with open('list1.pickle',"wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(list1,f)
        self.ids.RV_List.refreshview(list1)
        return list1

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(reparto.nome),'id':str(reparto)} for reparto in list1]   

    def refreshview(self, lista):
        self.data = [{'text': str(reparto.nome)} for reparto in lista] 

class RVBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):
     pass
    
class CardView(MDCard, RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    
    text= StringProperty()

    def remove_card(self):
        for item in list1: 
            if item.nome == self.ids.Label.text:
                list1.remove(item)
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.RV.refreshview(list1)


class CreaIntervento(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_file("KV.kv")

   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CreaIntervento().run()

.Kv
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primaryColor

    ScreenManager:
        id:screen_manager
        Screen1:           

<RV>
    viewclass:'CardView'
    RVBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size_hint: 1, None 
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        

<CardView>
    style:'elevated'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: dp(80)
    MDRelativeLayout:
        
        MDIconButton:
            id:func_icon
            icon: "trash-can"
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.9,'center_y':0.5}
            on_release:root.remove_card()
        MDLabel:
            id:Label
            text: root.text
            adaptive_size: True
            color: "grey"
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.5}
            bold: True

<Screen1> 
    name:"Aggiungi_Reparto"
    text_field:text_field
    rvNome:RV_List
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height:dp(100)
            MDTextField:
                id: text_field
                mode: "outlined"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y":.5}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: dp(400)

                MDTextFieldHintText:
                    text: "Nome nuovo reparto"

                MDTextFieldHelperText:
                    
                MDTextFieldMaxLengthText:
                    max_text_length: 30
                        
            MDButton:
                style: "filled"
                on_release: root.add_card()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y":.5}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: dp(100)

                MDButtonText:
                    text: "Aggiungi"

        RV:
            id:RV_List
                

I've tried to call a method from the RV, but without results.

OK I've find a solution:
def remove_card(self):
    for item in list1: 
        if item.nome == self.ids.Label.text:
            list1.remove(item)
    root= self.parent
    root= root.parent
    root.refreshview(list1)
    with open('list1.pickle',"wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(list1,f)
    return list1

Using parent I can use the refreshview() method of the RV class.
